# css Grandparent > Parent1, Parent2 > Child

Tags: html, css

I wrote something like this in styles, but it only works for the #header in the #register:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="register">
        <div id="header">Register</div>
    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <div id="header">Log in</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container > #register, #login > #header {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[You may only use an ID once per page](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id). Calling them both #header will behave unpredictable. Sometimes it'll work, sometimes it won't. Some browsers allow it in some cases, others in other cases. Unpredictable.
[Classes are ment for these cases](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.class). Also, as they are both decendants of `#container`, you do not need to select it twice:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="register">
        <div class="header">Register</div>
    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <div class="header">Log in</div>
    </div>
</div>

#container > .register{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

---

I also suggest you take a like at [the header element](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="register">
        <header>Register</header>
    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <header>Log in</header>
    </div>
</div>

#container > header{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Just as an addition [w3c - 8.1. Core attributes: id](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) `[...]A unique identifier for the element.
There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.[...]`

Comment: Added it to my answer, as well as to classes and the header element

Comment: That's not entirely true.
I use multiple ids and I have no problem with them.

But I wanted to merge the code and instead write:
`#container> #register> #header {...}`
`#container> #login> #header {...}`
That works, I wanted to write like in a question, but CSS does not know what I mean.

And btw, from definition:
`div > p`
Select and style every <p> element where the parent is a <div> element - so your examples do not have a right to exist.
So not thank you.

[CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: "Unpredictable": Sometimes it'll work, sometimes it won't. Some browsers allow it in some cases, others in other cases. Unpredictable. And wrong, please read the specs about an ID and CLASS in my answer as to why, It might work what you have now, but this isn't the way you should work. Just because you can use a wrench to hammer, doesn't mean you should ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm idiot...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="register">
        <form> <!-- I did not notice this -->
            <div id="header">Register</div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <form> // I did not notice this
            <div id="header">Log in</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container > #register, #login #header { /* correct (without ">") */
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

Everythink works... Sorry, my fault.